# Designing a PI controller for my power system

Tags: power-supply, power, design, control-system, pid-controller

I have a power system which is given as:

[image]

Using MATLAB, I found the system's response to be:
[image]

As you can see, the system is not stable.  So, I need to design a [PI controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PI_controller#PI_controller), so that, the transient performance of the \$\ p(s) \$ can be improved.

Therefore, my new system will be:
[image]

Please, know that:

- \$\ P(s) = C [sI-A]^{-1} B \$
- \$\ \Delta  x ' = A \Delta x + B u \$
- \$\ Y= C \Delta  x \$

Since we are dealing with a real power plant system, we should consider the input equations to be non-linear. Just for calculation purposes, let us assume that:

\$\ \Delta  x = [\Delta  \delta, \Delta  \omega. \Delta e_q' , \Delta E_d ] ^T \$

Let the angular speed of the rotor ω to be our input. (Just to make everything easier)

Therefor, C= [0 1 0 0]

Where ω can be defined as:

\$ ω' = \frac{1}{M} (P_M - P_E - D(ω-ω_0))\$

Please, know that all of these values are arbitrary, except for ω. (These values will be given to me later by the manufacturer of *P(s)*)

Anyhow, I tried to find \$\ K_I \$ and \$\ K_P \$ using the above equations. So, after using [Laplace transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) and many other calculations, I reached to the point where

\$\ H(\lambda)= \frac{\lambda T_W}{1+ \lambda T_W} (K_P + \frac{K_I}{\lambda}) \$

The question is:

What are the best values for \$\ K_I \$ and \$\ K_P\$ so that my power system is stable? And how can I know that?

Comment: What is your _P(s)_ transfer funtion?You need also to provide a value for \$T_w\$ which is first order time delay constant, which depends on the latency of your controller? `sisotool` command in matlab should solve your problem.
The solution for \$ K_I\$ and \$K_P \$ will be a range and not a mere single point. `sisotool` in matlab will let you play with \$ K_I\$ and \$K_P \$ until you are happy with the output.

Comment: I don't know what the value of \$T_w \$ is, it is just an arbitrary value. I don't care what number it has. The same thing goes with the other matrices (A, B and C), and I already give you the value of \$P(s)\$ in terms of these matrices. All I need is just to know: how can I chose the ***best*** values for \$K_I \$ and  \$K_P \$? I think I should learn more about the pole-placement method, maybe this is the solution. I will think about it later. Regarding the second part, thank you very much for the help. The `sisotool`  command was really helpful. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you don't have the P(s) transfer function. It can be an academic problem or an exercise over a real plant which an unknown model, but at least you should know WHAT INPUT makes P(s) to have that output. Is it an impulse, a step, a sine?

Lacking mathematical knowledge, you can follow some empirical rules, well spread in the industrial field, google for "ziegler nichols tuning method" or begin [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method).

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem. I don't know what is the exact expression for *P(s)*. But as for the input value, I have updated the question. I assumed that the angular speed of the rotor is our input. Finally, thank you very much for the help, I will read more about the Ziegler–Nichols method. I hope it could help me. Thank you

Comment: Well, Ziegler-Nichols is good method when you are allowed to bring your system to unstable phase, as it is required. By definition of ZN, you need to set the `Kp` to the value when you are experiencing the oscillations and then set the `Ki` from the table. But if you are dealing with the real thing, that is, most of the time, unacceptable.